# Res.redirect() vs res. Json(). Server for web and mobile

Tags: android, json, node.js, express, ejs

I am new to web development.  I had a web project with EJS templating.  It redirects directly from the server. Using res.redirect() . I want to create a server for web and mobile both.

Question is...  When i use res.json() it sends JSON data to client side.  Can work for both.

It is possible to use res.redirect() for both.  Web and mobile.

Pros and cons of res.rediret and res.json

Please explain.  I appreciate your suggestions in adv.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> It is possible to use res.redirect() for both. Web and mobile.

If you mean can you use res.redirect() as an alternative to res.json() then the answer is **NO**. res.redirect() is not an alternative to res.json. res.redirect() only sends a code and a URL back to the client, there is no data in the response. You will still need to use res.json or res.send to get the data you need. Every time you use res.redirect() you are sending a response to the client telling them to make a brand new request to another location. You're not sending any real data. The android app will not get any content till you use res.json or res.send. Redirects just tell the client go get the data from somewhere else.

Below are example responses to an android app when the server uses res.json and res.redirect

**res.redirect("/user")**

```
//Response to Android app

302 /user
```

The response above means what you want is located at "/user" so the mobile app will need to make a request to

**res.json(user)**

```
//Response to Android app

    {
        name: "Arpit Yadav",
        phone: 555-555
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`res.redirect` sends status code `302` (if not specified), and location (route) to browser, after which browser redirects the request to the specified location, whereas `res.json` sets `Content-Type: application/json` and sends data to the browser.

Redirection is generally meant for browser only, but, you can use it for mobile. In that case, you have to handle the logic to re-request with updated `location` received from server that is not recommended.

In nutshell, both have different purpose. `res.redirect` to move clients to different route and `res.json` to actually sends the data.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Mr. Mukesh Sharma.                                                   
 What if my server using res.redirect() and the client is android mobile app.